# Change pixels of certain color of an RGB image into another color Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have an RGB image `20x100x3` and I want to change the pixels having the color `17,167,243`, to this color `108,5,15` . If anyone could please advise how this can be done in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `img` as the input image array, this could be one approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
oldval = [17,167,243]
newval = [108,5,15]

idx = find(all(bsxfun(@eq,img,permute(oldval,[1 3 2])),3))
idx_all = bsxfun(@plus,idx(:),[0:2]*numel(img(:,:,1)))
img(idx_all) = repmat(newval,numel(idx),1)
```

Or a slightly modified one using `logical indexing` instead of the `linear indexing` based method used earlier -

```
mask = all(bsxfun(@eq,img,permute(oldval,[1 3 2])),3)
img(repmat(mask,1,1,3)) = repmat(newval,sum(mask(:)),1)
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to set oldval? Like if my oldval (R,G,B) is (17,167,243)?

Comment: @shepherd Check out the edits please. I missed out on setting the values up front earlier.

Comment: in the logical indexing solution it gives this error `Too many input arguments.` in the repmat function.

Comment: @shepherd Could you locate which repmat is it complaining about, as there are two repmats in there. Also which MATLAB version are you on?

Comment: `repmat(mask,1,1,3))` and I'm using Matlab 2013a

Comment: @shepherd Instead of `img(repmat(mask,1,1,3))`, could you try `img(repmat(mask,[1 1 3]))`. I am assuming it's a version issue.

Comment: @shepherd If you get a chance to do some runtime tests on your data, could you let me know how these two perform, as in which one is better?

Comment: just checked. The linear solution is faster, it takes `0.0081`, while with the logical one it takes `0.0138`

Comment: @shepherd Ah kool! I am guessing the memory requirements with the logical one isn't helping it. Thank you for the runtime updates!!

Comment: Yeah, and you are more than welcome, thanks for this efficient and beautiful answer.

Answer (score 0):

not the most elegant solution: find indexes of matrix `image(:,:, 1)` equal to 17 (use `find()`), then the same for `image( :,:, 2)` equal to 167, then `(:, :, 3)`... then identify all indexes that are in all three list (use `ismember()`). change the values of these pixels in the `(:, :, x)` matrices to the respective requested RGB values.